# Dual Boot Issue

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu installed along with Windows XP through Clone CD VCD Demon. Earlier it was working fine but after 2 months, i'm not getting the Dual Boot Option ( OS Selection Screen ) therefore i'm not able to login into Ubuntu, but my system shows that Ubuntu is still there. Can anybody help me out to clear this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the Ubuntu live CD.

Boot from it, fire up a terminal and enter the following command:

```
grub-install /dev/sda/
```

Then follow the on-screen instructions and after the installation finishes, enter this command:

```
update-grub
```

Reboot and enjoy. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Grub instalation was removed. To get dual boot option back, you need to install a boot manager, for example, Grub2, Lilo or Burg.

To get Grub back you can try Boot Repair:

1. Download iso from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

   1. Burn to a CD
   2. Boot from CD and use it to reinstall Grub

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

Grub, Ubuntu's bootloader, seems to have been removed for some reason.

### Solution

Boot with a Ubuntu Live CD.

Run the following commands from a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Click on the "Recommended repair" button, and reboot.

#### Explanation

Boot-Repair installed Grub to your internal hard drive. This allows you to choose which OS to boot when you start up your computer.

---

#### Glossary

> **[Bootloader](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm)**: a piece of code that runs before any operating system is running. A bootloader is used to boot other operating
>   systems. Each operating system usually has its own bootloader.
>
> **[GRUB (*Grand Unified Bootloader*)](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/GRUB-GRand-Unified-Bootloader)**: a bootloader package developed to support multiple operating systems and allow the user to select among them during boot-up. It is Ubuntu's default bootloader.
>
> **[Command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>